# Small blank boxes showing on my magento website in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, magento-1.9

Small blank boxes showing on my magento website in internet explorer.

[image]

Check quick link in footer and in products.

Any one have solution.

Answer (score 0):

Those are images that failed to load.  If you are in Chrome, turn on Developer Tools, go the the Network tab, and look for an error.

Comment: Thank you for reply but  those are not images. this kind of boxes only show at the end of line in only internet explorer

Comment: @Yuvrajshekhawat -- Is this page only anywhere?

Comment: This is due to <br/> tag, internet explorer is replacing <br/> tag with boxes. what we can do  for this?